# How do I prevent white objects from being displayed on a device

Tags: object, opengl-es

I have a game which displays objects properly on two devices (nexus 4 & 7), and in the emulator, but it shows white for some objects on a third device (samsung sgh-t679m).

Notice that on the "old" samsung, the background image and road image are rendered properly in colour, but the houses, planes, etc are white. I couldn't find a similar problem. Other issues report white objects consistently over all devices. Otherwise, the game action is working. The samsung has android 2.3.5

[image: On Ssamsung sgh-t679m]

[image: On nexus 4]

The main part of code is below:

```
public void render(World world, float deltaTime) {
    GL10 gl = glGraphics.getGL();

    if (world.bob.runningState == Bob.BOB_FALLING) {
        camera.getPosition().set(0, 2f, GameScreen.cameraZ + 2);
        camera.getLookAt().set(0, 0, GameScreen.cameraZ - 4);
    } 
    else {
        camera.getPosition().set(0, 5f, GameScreen.cameraZ + 2);
        camera.getLookAt().set(0, 0, GameScreen.cameraZ - 4);
    }

    camera.setMatrices(gl);

    gl.glEnable(GL10.GL_DEPTH_TEST); 
    gl.glEnable(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D);
    gl.glEnable(GL10.GL_LIGHTING);                  
    gl.glEnable(GL10.GL_COLOR_MATERIAL);
    ambientLight.enable(gl);
    directionalLight.enable(gl, GL10.GL_LIGHT0);

    renderBackgroundImages(gl, world.backgroundimages, deltaTime);
    renderRoads(gl, world.roads, deltaTime);
    renderCoins(gl, world.coins, deltaTime);
    renderObstacles(gl, world.obstacles, deltaTime);
    renderOverheads(gl, world.overheads, deltaTime);
    renderHouses(gl, world.houses, deltaTime);
    renderBob(gl, world.bob, deltaTime); 
    renderInvaders(gl, world.invaders, deltaTime);
    renderShots(gl, world.shots, deltaTime);

    gl.glDisable(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D);   


    gl.glDisable(GL10.GL_COLOR_MATERIAL);
    gl.glDisable(GL10.GL_LIGHTING);
    gl.glDisable(GL10.GL_DEPTH_TEST);       
}
```

Comment: We couldn't really do anything but guess, which is not really the idea of this site. The most useful part of the code would probably be showing how you load and set up your textures. Formats, sizes, etc. It looks like some of your textures are not working.

Comment: I have added a code section showing how objects are rendered.

Comment: This code is not helpful, since it does not show how textures are created or how textures are used...

Comment: Yes, the code we would need to see would contain calls like `glTexImage*()`, `glTexParameter*()`, etc.